# Complexity of this triple for loop?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

```
for(i=1;i<=2237;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<=2237;j++)
    {
        for(k=1;k*(i*i+j*j)<=5000000;k++)
        {
            a[k*(i*i+j*j)]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here 5 * 10^6 can be assumed as n, and 2237 is approximated as sqrt(n). I am able to figure out complexities of the outer 2 loops, it's the innermost loop that's got me confused.

Comment: It's O(1) because there's no variable input size. Yes the constant is high, but it's constant nonetheless. (For clarity: you need a _varying_ `n` to calculate complexity w.r.t. `n`.)

Comment: That said: if you take replace `2237` with `n`, your inner loop is repeated O(n^2) times, and the k loop iterates up n*(n^2+n^2). i.e. O(n^3). Overall complexity should be O(n^5). (But that's intuitively; no idea how to prove it.)

Comment: As I mentioned below the code snippet above, 5*10^6 is to be replaced by n, and henceforth 2237 by sqrt(n).

Comment: Complexity of `i` loop `sqrt(n)`, Complexity of `j` loop `sqrt(n)`, Complexity of `k` loop `sqrt(n)`. Overall Complexity `n*sqrt(n)`.

Comment: look at google/benchmark as well. there you can figure out complexity by benchmarking it for different input sizes :)

Answer (score 0):

If the input dictates the number of iterations in the innermost loop (as you have described it):

The outer loop runs `sqrt(N)` times, then the the middle loop runs on **average** `sqrt(N)/2` on each iteration of the outer loop.  Then the inner loops runs N times on every iteration of the middle loop.

So.... `sqrt(N) * sqrt(N)/2 * N == (N-Squared / 2)`

Hence `O(N-Squared)`

If the input dictates the number of iterations in the outermost loop such that the innermost loop iteration count is always a squared value of the outer's interaction count:

```
`N * N/2 * N-Squared = N**4 (N to the power of 4)`.  Hence, `O(N**4)`
```